# Использование OpenSSL вместо LibreSSL

Tags: python, openssl

Только решил начать изучать Python, но при запуске первого кода появилась проблема:
NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. Наверное, я плохо искал, но в интернете я так и не нашел решение данной проблемы. Использую MacOS Sonoma. Устанавливал Python через Homebrew, использую PyCharm

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.